# How I solve the problem of writing an formula with just one accolade?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, equations, loops, format-files

I should write the following formula: [image: pp]
This is the code:

```
\begin{equation}
 Q_{sp}=\left\{\stackrel{\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}\dots \kappa_{Zp-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots\mu_{Zp} (1+\sum^{n}_{l=1} \frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}
\dots \kappa_{l-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots \mu_{l}})} \dots 1\leq Zp\leq number\_pol}{\frac{1}{1+\sum^{n}_{l=1}\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1} 
\dots \kappa_{l-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots \mu_{l}}} \dots Zp=0} 
\end{equation}
```

How I solve the problem of writing it  by just one accolade without having this mistake

```
!Missing  \right. inserted
```

Comment: you should add `\right.` immediately after the last line of the stack.  `\left` always has to be paired with `\right`, even if one of them is empty.  (that's where the period after `\right` comes in.)

Comment: You should use the `dcases` environment from `mathtools` instead.

Comment: How can I use dcases environment?

Comment: @M.amani: I've posted a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from the manual from AMSmath package page 8.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  B’&=-\partial\times E,\\
  E’&=\partial\times B - 4\pi j,
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution with your equation:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 Q_{sp}=\left\{\stackrel{\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}\dots \kappa_{Zp-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots\mu_{Zp} (1+\sum^{n}_{l=1} \frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}\dots \kappa_{l-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots \mu_{l}})} \dots 1\leq Zp\leq number\_pol}{\frac{1}{1+\sum^{n}_{l=1}\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1} \dots \kappa_{l-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\dots \mu_{l}}} \dots Zp=0}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dcases`, and some improvements for the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  Q_{sp}=\begin{dcases}\stackrel{\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1} ... \kappa_{Zp-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2} ... \mu_{Zp} \bigl(1+\sum^n_{l=1} \frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}
    \dotsm \kappa_{l-1}\mathstrut}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2} ... \mu_{l}}\bigr)} ... 1\leq Zp\leq \text{number\_pol}}{\frac{\strut1}{1+\sum^n_{l=1}\frac{\kappa_{0}\kappa_{1}
     ... \kappa_{l-1}}{\mu_{1}\mu_{2} ... \mu_{l}}} ... Zp=0}
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]